# How to preserv php string to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I am trying to copy a string in a php array to localStorage and the string is a date in this format: 2016-06-15
But the string becomes calculated before stored.
How do I preserv it as a string?
Example:

```
<?php
  $test = array('2015-10-05','20151005');
  echo $test[0]."<br>";
  echo $test[1];
  echo '<script>localStorage["test1a"] = '.$test[0].';</script>';
  echo '<script>localStorage["test2a"] = '.$test[1].';</script>';
?>
<script>localStorage["test1b"] = "2015-10-05";</script>
<script>localStorage["test2b"] = "20151005";</script>
```

This will output:

```
2015-10-05
20151005
```

And in localStorage:

```
test1a 2000
test1b 2015-10-05
test2a 20151005
test2b 20151005
```

Comment: because it is outputted as `localStorage["test1a"] = 2015-10-05;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  $test = array('2015-10-05','20151005');
  echo $test[0]."<br>";
  echo $test[1];
  echo '<script>localStorage["test1a"] = "'.$test[0].'";</script>';
  echo '<script>localStorage["test2a"] = "'.$test[1].'";</script>';
?>
<script>localStorage["test1b"] = "2015-10-05";</script>
<script>localStorage["test2b"] = "20151005";</script>
```

Note the Additional Quotes added '"' wrapping the array variable.
To explain why it does not store the value but calculate it is because you are throwing a string at browser and it interpretes as HTML or Javascript in this case.

Comment: Oh, what a blunder! Thank you Akshay!